# JavaFX GridPane: Expand button to fill multiple cells

Tags: layout, javafx

Using JavaFX's `GridPane` container, how can I set a button (or anything else) to expand horizontally until it fills all assigned cells?

I add the button to my GridPane using this line:

```
grid.add(button, 3, 0, 3, 1);
```

But the button is only as wide as its text, which is about 2.5 cells. I want it to entirely occupy all 3 assigned cells.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do

```
// allow button to grow:
button.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);

// ask GridPane to make button fill it's cells:
GridPane.setFillWidth(button, true);
```

Comment: This does not work for me. All the buttons are the same size.

Comment: Then there's presumably something else you're doing wrong. Post your own question with a [MCVE]